# Converter string em objeto XML

Tags: python, soap

Estou consumindo um Web Service SOAP e consigo chamar através do Python utilizando o módulo `zeep`.

```
client = Client(wsdl='meu_endpoint?WSDL')

print(client.service.ObterDividaAtivaPorCPF('user','senha','cpf'))
```

Ele retorna uma string neste formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu converto essa string em um objeto XML para que eu possa realizar o parse? Eu gostaria de buscar o valor de uma determinada tag.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode importar a biblioteca `xml.etree.ElementTree` e com ela efetuar o parser e leitura do dos dados do XML.

---

Para efetuar o parser, você pode utilizar o método `fromstring`, para buscar uma tag, utilize o método `find` no objeto XML, abaixo um exemplo bem simples de uso:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#Exemplo de XML qualquer
xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
xml += ' <note>'
xml += '  <to>Alguém</to>'
xml += '  <from>De outra pessoa</from>'
xml += '  <heading>Recado</heading>'
xml += '  <body>Não esqueça...</body>'
xml += ' </note>'

#Efetuar o parser do XML
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

#Exibe o conteúdo do elemento body
print(tree.find("body").text)
```

O método `find` retorna `None` caso não encontre o elemento.

---

> Veja esse exemplo online: https://repl.it/repls/HungryPaltrySyndrome
>
> Documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: O que não estou conseguindo é pegar o retorno da chamada ao Web Service e transformá-lo em um XML. Não achei nenhuma forma que faça o próprio retorno já vir no formato XML (conforme seu ótimo exemplo).

Comment: A chamada e o retorno do WS você consegue fazer? O retorno atualmente é uma string?

Comment: Sim, o retorno é uma string. Confirmo isso usando o função type que retorna str.